# How do I get three columns to concatenate into one combo-box in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, concatenation

I have a combo-box in an Access 2010 form that I want to show the concatenation of three fields in three separate columns as a result.  Currently, I only get the first column to show upon selection even though all three show in the dropdown.  The previous questions I have looked at seem to deal with platforms I'm not using.

In a qry, I have the following simple SQL statement that combines all three into a Desc column.

```
SELECT tblReLetArea.CWHContractNo, tblReLetArea.ReLetAreaLot, tblReLetArea.ReLetAreaName, tblReLetArea.[CWHContractNo] & ": " & [ReLetAreaLot] & " - " & [ReLetAreaName] AS [Desc]
FROM tblReLetArea;
```

I have attempted variations but nothing changes and I don't get any error messages.

Comment: your query selects 4 fields (the last one is the Desc), start by checking that you are trying to take the 4th field (or delete the first 3 fields from the query)

Comment: Awesome. That solved it. Many thanks Ofer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set two things:

The amount of columns in the combobox (`combobox.ColumnCount`) must be set to 4

The column widths of the combobox (`combobox.ColumnWidths`) must be set to 0;0;0 to hide the first 3 columns

Note that you could indeed remove the first 3 columns from your query altogether, or reorder the columns. That would influence the availability of the columns in VBA.

Comment: Many thanks Eric. If I shift it all to code I will come back to your comment.